# Query Data and arrange data Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I have 5 columns as `[ ID , Type_1 , Type_2 , Salary , Value ]`. I want to query data from SQL Server using Laravel fremwork.

`if the Type_1 = AAA and Type_2 = BBB` I want to sum all salary that have in `type_1 'AAA' and Type_2 'BBB'` and get all data as the one Item **dynamically**. See following image for more details.

[image]

Comment: show as what you have tried

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try?

Comment: You have a tag MySQL and in your question you say "query data from sql server" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like in this way

```
$results=Salary::where('Type_1', 'AAA')->where('Type_2', 'BBB')->sum('salary')->get();
```

Comment: thank you but i have a big data so i want dynamically code for solved this issue @Tanvir Ahmed

Comment: then you can use chunk